# python tcp socket wrong value

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I used python connect A rfid device by tcp socket.

here is the base code

```
HOST = '192.168.1.159'
PORT = 4001
from socket import *
def main():
    tcp_client_socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
    tcp_client_socket.connect((HOST,PORT))
    while True:
        recv_data = tcp_client_socket.recv(10240)
        if recv_data:
            print(recv_data)
        else:
            break
    tcp_client_socket.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

then I'll receive the value like this

```
b'\xa0\x13\x01\x89\x1c4\x000\x083\xb2\xdd\xd9\x01@\x00\x00\x00\xa4pK'
```

but the tcp socket test tool receive the value like this

```
A0 13 01 89 1C 34 00 30 08 33 B2 DD D9 01 40 00 00 00 A4 70 4B
```

[image]

check the Highlight part.

I tred

```
print(recv_data.decode())
```

then receive

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I don't know how to fix this issue. can someboy help? please.

Comment: The default display of a byte string displays an ASCII character if it is in the printable ASCII range.  so `b'\x34' == b'4'` and `b'\x40' == b'@'`.  It's just a *display* representation.  But I see you found `.hex()` gives you a hexadecimal representation.  The bytes received are the same in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question

```
print(recv_data.hex())
```

then receive

```
a00a018900000500000001c6
```

and send data

```
    packet = bytearray()
    packet.append(0xA0)
    packet.append(0x04)
    packet.append(0x01)
    packet.append(0x74)
    packet.append(0x00)
    packet.append(0xE7)
    packet.append(0xA0)
    packet.append(0x04)
    packet.append(0x01)
    packet.append(0x89)
    packet.append(0x01)
    packet.append(0xD1)
    tcp_client_socket.send(packet)
```

Comment: Instead of manual append, you can do `packet = bytes([0xa0,0x04, ... ])` or `b'\xa0\x04\x01...'`.